# Converting to send API Data to other components to be used in Line Charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to see how I can set this data to props or what I need to do to be able to use this data in my individual Line Chart components using Chart.js. The Api Call is working and I'm getting all the data I need on 2 separate Api.js files and am able to get this to render. However now that I have that, i'm wondering what my best option is for sending this over to be able to be displayed in the line charts. I'm also getting errors that `Each Child in a list should have a key prop` which is where you see me attempting to assign keys. I'm inexperienced with this so any help and direction would be appreciated.

Here is an api call getting data I'm trying to share across components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

let headers = {
  'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com',
  'User-Agent': 'FileService_Integration_V2.1',
  'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXX_XXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

class JobsTableApi extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }    

  fetchData = () => {    
     let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,80,81,82,83,86,84,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,103,104,105,106,107,109,111,113,115,120,123,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,477,479,480,481],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}}

    fetch('https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then( data => this.setState({ data })
      );
    }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

      if (data === null) return 'Loading...';

    return (
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(data["data"]).map(item =>
          <div>
            <h2>
              {data["data"][item][3].value} -- {data["data"][item][6].value}
              <br />
              <a>{data["data"][item][40].value}</a>
            </h2>
            <h5>Overall Project Totals:</h5>
              <p key="AdjContractAmt">Adj Contract Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][80].value)},</p>
              <p key="DesignHours">Design Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][88].value)},</p>
              <p key="DesignAmount">Design Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][91].value)},</p>
              <p key="SubRoughHours">SubRough Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][92].value)},</p>
              <p key="SubRoughAmount">SubRough Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][95].value)},</p>
              <p key="RoughHours">Rough Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][96].value)},</p>
              <p key="RoughAmount">Rough Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][98].value)},</p>
              <p key="FinishHours">Finish Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][104].value)},</p>
              <p key="FinishAmount">Finish Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][107].value)},</p>
              <p key="CloseHours">Close Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][477].value)},</p>
              <p key="CloseAmount">Close Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][480].value)},</p>
              <p key="CurrentHours">CURRENT/ACTUAL Hours: {Math.round(data["data"][item][479].value)},</p>
              <p key="CurrentAmount">CURRENT/ACTUAL Amount: ${Math.round(data["data"][item][224].value)}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default JobsTableApi;
```

I've heard that redux is good for this? But i've also heard that is mainly for larger applications, once I get this data to be used in the line charts thats about all I'd need.

File structure:

```
>src
    >components
        >charts
            >multipleLineCharts.js
        >API
            >api.js1
            >api.js2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where will the Line Chart components be in relation to the component that is retrieving the data (parent, child, sibling)?

Comment: So as of right now i'm using the api files to pull the data in my components folder in an API folder, which also houses a charts folder with all my line charts where I want the data to go. then in my app.js i'm using to display these line charts all on one page.

Comment: A few ways you could do this. One is to call your data in your App.js file (I'm assuming this is the parent file to the charts) and pass the data to each chart. Another way is in App.js you can define the data props, one for each api file I guess, and in your api files set the state with the retrieved data. You can then pass the data props to the chart files.

Comment: This is where I'm unsure on how to do this. For example, right now [80] would be a field I need, but I can't do props.[80], like how you'd do props.name. So I'm unsure on how to convert this to be able to call each field on my components as needed

Comment: You can get the data, have a function construct the data in a way that is usable for you and pass that as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

that is about identity of divs inside structure:

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

When You mapping the array of elements then:

```
  {Object.keys(data["data"]).map(item, i =>
          <div key = {i}>

          </div>
  }
```

For displaying charts i suggest to use
https://recharts.org/

Comment: It's not recommended to use the index as a key for each element. It's better to use some other piece of information like if `item.id` is available to store as the key.